# iOS how to scroll small child scrollview in large parent scrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I have added small size UIScrollview in the large size UIScrollview in storyboard.
When I try horizontal scrolling in small child scrollview, the large parent scrollview is scrolled.
What I want is when I scroll in child, child will be scrolled, and when I scroll in parent area, parent will be scrolled.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a gestureRecognizer to your scrollViews, then set the ones that are tapped to scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES and the other to .scrollEnabled = NO